# Gradle for AngularJS Application

Tags: angularjs, gradle

I´m pretty new to gradle and currently there is question that bugs me. The situation appears as follows: Based on a bower technology stack I implemented an Angular App. The app as it is doesn't  change nor has it to be built in any way since there are just static javascript and HTML pages. In my opinion the used versions of angular, bootstrap and other libraries should also stay the same due to compatibility of the single libraries so these files also shouldn't change. Is this a correct behavior or should I get at least the latest build of the used libraries version as I deploy the application?
Also less is used in the application. Is there a way to compile the CSS every time I run the gradle build file or should I deliver just the compiled and finished CSS file?
As a result I´m also not quite sure if it's recommended at all using gradle to deploy an "static" angular application.

I hope someone out there can help me to answer the questions above. As you can guess, I´m not very experienced at deploying of such angular applications since this is my first project with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes for all package managers, not just gradle but npm, gem, nuget, maven, whatever.

Use static dependancy version numbers. Otherwise you will end up finding breaking dependencies in QA or Prod rather than  production.

This means you need to be aware of security fixes in your dependencies.

When you need a feature or fix in a new version of your dependencies, unlock the versions, rebuild and test in dev. Re-lock the dependencies and send to QA for verification.